# weird behavior of numpy when it calculates a vector and matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following weird behavior of `numpy` where numpy can't multiply a `(n,n)` matrix with `(n,)` matrix and convert the later to `(1,n)` matrix. I tried different examples and it worked fine. `u` and `s` were obtained from `svd` function as follows:

```
 [u, s, vt] = np.linalg.svd(G)
 svd_estimate = np.matmul(u * s, vt)
```

and `G` is a numpy matrix. I tried to `squeeze(s)` but also didn't work. What am I missing? numpy version is `'1.19.2'`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what `svd` produces for a `matrix` versus `array`:

```
In [24]: np.linalg.svd(np.matrix(np.eye(3)))
Out[24]: 
(matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]]),
 array([1., 1., 1.]),
 matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]]))
In [25]: np.linalg.svd(np.eye(3))
Out[25]: 
(array([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]),
 array([1., 1., 1.]),
 array([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]))
```

With the array values, as shown in the docs:

```
In [27]: u,s,vh=_25
In [28]: np.dot(u*s,vh)
Out[28]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

With the matrix results we have use `np.multiply`

```
In [37]: u,s,vh=_24
In [38]: np.multiply(u,s)
Out[38]: 
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
In [39]: np.multiply(u,s)*vh
Out[39]: 
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```